# How to conclude that $r^t(E\cos(\theta t)+Fsin(\theta t))$ ossilates with increasing magnitude?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

Given:

$r^t(E\cos(\theta t)+Fsin(\theta t))$

Assume $r>1$, $E>0$, $t\ge0$ and $F$ is not known.

How do we conclude that the given expression oscillates with increasing magnitude?

My attempt:

1. Since $r>1$, $r^t$ will tend to infinity as $t$ tends to infinity.
2. Therefore, if the expression is supposed to oscillate with increasing magnitude, then $(E\cos(\theta t)+Fsin(\theta t))$ will need to change regularly change sign. I know that the $\cos$ and $sin$ function will alternate from -1 to 1 but I don't know how to apply that property to this question.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter what $E$ and $F$ are, we can write

$r^t(E\cos(\theta t)+Fsin(\theta t)) = r^t \sqrt{E^2 + F^2}(\frac{E}{\sqrt{E^2 + F^2}}\cos(\theta t) + \frac{F}{\sqrt{E^2 + F^2}}\sin(\theta t)), \tag{1}$

and since

$(\frac{E}{\sqrt{E^2 + F^2}})^2 + (\frac{F}{\sqrt{E^2 + F^2}})^2 = 1 \tag{2}$

there exists a $\phi \in \Bbb R$ with

$\sin \phi = \frac{E}{\sqrt{E^2 + F^2}}; \; \cos \phi = \frac{F}{\sqrt{E^2 + F^2}}. \tag{3}$

Using (3) in (1) we have

$r^t(E\cos(\theta t)+Fsin(\theta t)) = r^t \sqrt{E^2 + F^2}(\sin \phi \cos(\theta t) + \cos \phi\sin(\theta t)), \tag{4}$

and using the usual trigonometric identity $\sin (\alpha + \beta) = \sin \alpha \cos \beta + \sin \beta \cos \alpha$ we have

$r^t(E\cos(\theta t)+Fsin(\theta t)) = r^t \sqrt{E^2 + F^2}\sin(\theta t + \phi). \tag{5}$

Next, note that $r > 1$ allows us to write $r^t = e^{t \ln r}$; since $\ln r > 0$, this is an increasing exponential as $t \to \infty$.  So

$r^t(E\cos(\theta t)+Fsin(\theta t)) = e^{t\ln r} \sqrt{E^2 + F^2}\sin(\theta t + \phi) \tag{6}$

is now easily seen to undergo oscillations of ever-increasing amplitude as $t \to \infty$, since the $\sin$ factor is simply phase-shifted by $\phi$.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Thank you for answer. It is indeed enlightening. However, I never would have figure it out myself as it will never occur to me to do rewrite the equation as in (1). Could you please elaborate more on what made you write it that way and if there are alternative workings too?

Comment: @mauna:  well, I learned about the "trick" used in (1) when I first studied differential equations, about the time the Rosetta Stone was carved! ;-)!!! It is the way of expressing the solution of $\ddot z + \theta^2 z = 0$ as a single $\sin$ or $\cos$ function (a variant works for $\cos$); a linear combination of $\sin \theta t$ and $\cos \theta t$ is just a phase shifted $\sin$ or $\cds$ function.Also, in electrical engineering, which I studied as well as math, one sees this sort of thing a lot.  So I just had it in my "experience bag", as it were.  It's a pretty common "trick", (more . . . )

Comment: @mauna:  (continuation of last comment) you'll run into it again at some point.  I'll have to think about alternatives, so maybe more later . . .

Comment: @ mauna:  the only other thing I've got on this right now is to look at $E\cos \theta t + F \sin \theta t$ as the real part if $(E - iF)(\cos \theta t + i \sin \theta t$ and then find $R, \phi$ such that $E + iF = Re^{i\phi}$.  I'll leave the details to you; if  you have questions, post another comment and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @ mauna:  my final point is that it's usually easier to see the oscillations for $\sin$ or $\cos$ than for a linear combination of them; I wanted to move things in that direction and was (am) lucky enough to know how!